# React: send data from Child component to Parent component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, onchange

**This is a react beginners exercise so I'm looking for the simplest solution. I'm currently learning React so any helpful comments would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!**

**This is the exercise:**

In a functional component, create a `div` which contains 2 inputs and one button.

Each of these should be a separate child component, all rendered by a parent component called App.

You should collect the data from the inputs and make it available in the parent component (using a function would work for this).

Input 1 should collect the user's email.
Input 2 should collect the user's password.

When the button (also a separate component) is clicked then you should alert the data collected by the two inputs.

You should use the `onChange` and `onClick` events

**I'm not quite sure what I have to do with the Button component. This is what I have so far for the exercise but I think it's wrong?......**

**APP.JS**

```
import React from 'react'
import Email from './components/Email'
import Password from './components/Password'

const App = () => {

  getData  = data => '${data}'

  return ( <div>
              <Email getData = {getData} />
              <Password getData = {getData} />
           </div>
    )
  }

export default App
```

**EMAIL.JS**

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {

    let email = '';

        return (
            <button onClick ={()=>props.getData({email})}></button>
         );
      }
export default Email;
```

**PASSWORD.JS**

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {

    let password = '';

        return (
            <button onClick ={()=>props.getData({password})}></button>
         );
      }
export default Password;
```

**BUTTON.JS**

Comment: Can you create a sandbox link for same?

Comment: What they are asking you to do is use the onChange handler of an input item on the password and email components. When there is a change, pass the information up to your App component. This is where your state is going to be stored for your email and password. When you push the button (onClick) it is going to alert the state that you have in your main component

Comment: Have you covered useState hooks for functional components yet?

Comment: Briefly looked into State hooks, but I wasn't sure if I could use State hooks with functional components

Comment: I dont think cristina has used any hooks till now.

Comment: Create an account here: https://codesandbox.io/ it will help you alot during your learning and asking for help. So for your email and password components. How do you plan to get input from the user? (hint: there shouldn't be any buttons inside of email or password.js

Comment: I put together a small example for you to show you the concept, take a look and rework your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cookies-r3f1d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'll take a look! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution and a sandbox for the same.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Email from "./components/Email";
import Password from "./components/Password";
import Button from "./components/Button";
const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = useState("");
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);
  if (submit) {
    console.log("email ", email);
    console.log("password ", password);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Email setEmail={setEmail} />
      <Password setpassword={setpassword} />
      <Button setSubmit={setSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Password.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Password = ({ setpassword, submit }) => {
  return (
    <>
      Get Password
      <input type="password" onChange={e => setpassword(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
};
export default Password;
```

**Email.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Email = ({ setEmail }) => {
  return (
    <>
      Get Email
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
};
export default Email;
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ setSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setSubmit(true);
      }}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  );
};
export default Button;
```

I would strongly suggest you go to reactjs.org and go through the documents before starting any course. Please don't copy paste. I hope it helps.

Comment: Here is a working sanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-water-f7tdl

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful :)